# dbids from model not rendering properly in forge viewer

Tags: angular, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using Forge viewer to load model from BIM 360.
I am using Forge viewer's visibility manager to show specific dbids from model.
I have written below code to show the specific dbids using VisibilityManager

```
// Restore camera state
this.viewer.restoreState(
  viewerState,
);
this.viewer.clearSelection();

// Hide model from viewer
this.viewer.model.setAllVisibility(0);
this.viewer.impl.toggleGhosting(false);

// Enable visibility of id's, which are selected while creating assembly
this.viewer.impl.visibilityManager.show( 
  dbids,
  this.viewer.model);
```

Sometimes viewer not showing all dbids passed to the show() function
I need to zoom in or out or any event on the forge viewer  and then viewer showing all passed dbids.

This feature used to work without any problems in the past. However, for the past few days, we've been encountering this issue.

I have tried below solutions -

1. Checked by invalidating viewer after `show()` method

   ```
   this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true,true,true);
   ```
2. Checked by changing camera positions after `show()`
3. Checked by forge viewer’s fitToView() method after `show()`
   `this.viewer.fitToView(dbids,this.viewer.model)`

Comment: Seems like this is bug in the latest viewer version i.e 7.93.1.

I have downgraded the version to 7.92 and no issue while rendering objects

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior using version 7.93.1

Could you please share steps to reproduce it. Please share the browser used, and model if possible through aps[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com